# Get base model types on client with Prisma and NextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js, types, prisma

Prisma makes a namespace available that has a ton of useful types for the different api methods. However, I can't find one for just the base models. For instance, I have the following model:

```
model Instruction {
  id              String       @id @default(cuid())
  order           String
  description     String       @db.VarChar(500)
  optional        Boolean      @default(false)
  recipe          Recipe       @relation(fields: [recipeId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  recipeId        String
  ingredientLinks Ingredient[]
}
```

With all the generated types Prisma offers, I'd expect there to be a generated `Instruction` type available for the client that automatically updates when i change my schema that would be something like:

```js
// basically just an exact reflection of the model
interface Instruction {
  id: string;
  order: string;
  description: string;
  ...etc
}
```

Is this available, or do I have to update my client types manually?